# How can I load .html file in a specified div tag using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to load a .html file in a other html file 
ManageAccount page should load in a div with id main, when manage acount is clicked,
but it loading the whole page again in div.
[image]
Result is fethching all the html page insted of new html page
can any one suggest me please.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var btn;
      $('button[type="button"]').click(function() { 
        btn = this.id;
        alert(btn);
        $.ajax({
          url: btn.html,
          type: 'GET',
          //async:'false';
          dataType: 'html',
          success: function(result){
            $("#main").html(result);
            alert(result);
          }
       });

      });
    });
</script>
```

Manage Account
                        Profile
                        Application
                        Status
                        Query

Comment: In your `ajax` call you must pass in the url as a string `url: "btn.html"`

Comment: btn is button id the name is generated on which button is clicked like btn=profile so it will load profile.html.

Comment: So you should type `btn + '.html'`

Comment: If you consider that one of the answers is valid, please, mark it as valid to help others to find similar problems and solutions. @rikky

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap in quotes at least the extension of the file `url: btn + '.html'`.

Also, you can use jQuery `.load()` method directly:

```
$('#main').load(btn + '.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `jQuery.load()`

```
 $('button').on("click", function() { 
       $("#main").load("btn.html"); 
 });
```

Comment: i tried with load but problem is, it is not working in chrome $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("#main").load("manageAccount.txt");
    });